# unexpected output -scanf and function check

Tags: c, function, scanf

So i am trying to write this program but i get 10 no matter what the input is. My function seems correct to me so is it a scanf issue?

Write a program to input 10 integers and decide how many of them satisfy the
following rule:
abcd = (ab + cd)2 e.g. 3025=(30+25)
Use a function that receives an integer parameter returns 1 if it satisfies the above
rule, returns 0 otherwise.

```
int check(int n);
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j = 0;
    printf("Input 10 integers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (check(n) == 1)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
int check(int x)
{
    if (((x / 100) + (x % 100)) * ((x / 100) + (x % 100))) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you know if "it's a scanf issue" without actually *checking* the results of your `scanf` call? The documented result of that function is there for a reason; use it. Then, turn loose the debugger-dogs and single step through your code. Even something as simple as inline-instrumenting your supposed vs actual values would probably tell you were things go off the rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is the `check` function,

```
if (((x / 100) + (x % 100)) * ((x / 100) + (x % 100)))  // <---- anything not zero will be true
{
    return 1;
}
```

The expression inside `if`  will convert any integer which is not zero to true. The expression as it is written is `if (x * x)` which only false if `x == 0`.

Comment: E.g. `if ((((x / 100) + (x % 100)) * ((x / 100) + (x % 100))) == x)`